# How to output a specific character in the array

Tags: c#

I have an exercise in a course project which I've been struggling to solve B), I can’t find information on the Internet how to output a specific character in the list of array. The assignment is:

The elements of the array are names of towns beginning with an uppercase letter.

- A) entering the elements of the array (no more than 50)
- B) output all towns in whose names the letter "e" or "E" occurs 2,3
  or 4 times, and the letter "r" does not occur even once.

I only wrote A) and it is:

```
string\[\] city;
city = new string \[50\] {i listed 50 cities}
```

The language I use is C#.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking us to do the second half of your assignment for you? Please try it yourself first. If you run into a specific problem, include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with an explanation of the current behavior, the desired behavior, and (if applicable) example input/output for each. Please see [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/10601203) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/10601203)

Comment: Try splitting the initial problem into smaller ones, e.g. 1. Entering names of the cities (loop, ask user to enter city name or quit, put name into a list; turn list into the array), 2. check how many given char appears in the given string (loop), case is ignored 3. Count how many items of the array contains `e`

Comment: Tip: An old trick for counting occurrences of a character in a string is to take the length of the string and subtract the length of the string after all of the target characters are removed. For example, the count of `o`'s in `'Foo bar'`: the string has 7 characters, remove the `o`'s and you get `'F bar'` which is 5 characters. `7 - 5` is `2`.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the code: `string[] cities = { "varna", "burgas", "var", "sofia", "eseema", "peteeee" };`

And here you go

```
    foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            if (city.ToLower().Contains("r"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(city);
            }

            var eCount = city.ToLower().Count(x => x.ToString().Equals("e"));
            if (eCount >= 2 && eCount <= 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(city);
            }

        }
```

You can do something like that.

Comment: Minor detail - code will output cities with 'r' when it should not. Easy to fix thou. Good answer.

Comment: Sorry, about that. Just tried to write fast answer, to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can`t upvote your answer cus i have 7/15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a string-array with:

```
var cities = new string[] { "New York", "Chicago", ... , "Stockholm", "Helsinki" };
```

However, the assignment seem to ask the student to create a program that will accept input from the user of the program. For this you can use Console.ReadLine:

```
var cities = new string[50];
int i=0;
do {
    cities[i++] = Console.ReadLine();
} while(cities[i-1].Length>1 && i<50);
```

Keep entering cities until i reaches 50 or user sends an empty string.

To output cities only containing 'E' or 'e' and not cities containing 'r':

```
foreach(var city in cities)
{
    if((city.Contains("e") || city.Contains("E")) && !city.Contains("r"))
        Console.WriteLine(city);
}
```

You need to count the number E or e occurs in the city-string, but I leave that as a task for you to figure out. I hope this is helpful on your path to the solution.

Answer (score -4):

We can print a string in C using puts(), printf(), for loop, and recursion method. We have to pass a string character array name in the puts() function as an argument to print the string in the console. We can use the %s format specifier in the printf() function to print the character array in the console.

Comment: This question is not about C (see the tag and question body). Those functions don't exist in C#.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).